# Powershell Reads SQL Service Account NetworkService incorrectly no Space

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell command to pull out the server account user for SQL Server.

When I do this it gives me the result "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE".  However the issue is I cannot take this and add it to a group.

The only way to do this is to add a space for "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

I am doing all this through chef i could put in a replace to fix on the fly but i have seen this for other accounts.

Any proper way to fix.

Powershell command is:

`$item = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $env:computername |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "MSSQLSERVER"}
$item.StartName`

Comment: What sort of group? AD, Permissions, Chef, other?

Comment: It is just a local windows group that I am trying to add it to.

Comment: This server fault answer... http://serverfault.com/a/469961/293951 ...explains how to do it via the GUI, so a quick Google should get you the programmatic way of achieving the same via Chef?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262326/1368849)

```
$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://./Power Users,group"
$group.Add("WinNT://SYSTEM,user")
```

It might not 100%, as I haven't tested, but should give you enough information to amend to suit your needs.