# Add-LocalGroupMember is not recognized as a cmdlet , function , script or file on windows server 2012

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, windows-server-2012

Is there a way to add addlocalgroupmember module on windows server 2012? I didnot find any.
I need to add AD account on local admin group but i couldn't find a way.

The closest i was able to reach is to install activedirectory-powershell feature using the following command but that too didn't help.

Basically i need to find a way to run a powershell command similar to the below one on win server 2012 -

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "domain\user"
```

Comment: according to the MSDocs page for that cmdlet, it REQUIRES at least ps5.1 ... and you don't have that installed, apparently.

Comment: for a workaround, look into the ADSI stuff - it provides a way to address the local accounts.

Comment: See: [Add user to local group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262326/1701026)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't really need to complicate things much here. In reality you can achieve what you want with a one-line without installing any module since you're not modifying AD you can simply use.

```
net localgroup Administrators /add domain\username
```

Comment: What if the requirement is to use PowerShell?

Comment: @SouthFresh Powershell can interpret most of cmd commands so you can run that in a powershell script or terminal and the result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Windows Management Framework (WMF) v5.1 that can be downloaded here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

After installing, you will can use the module `Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` and the command `Add-LocalGroupMember` will work just fine.